# DJANGO AllAuth Required Fields in User Model

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I was using djoser, but ran into snags customizing emails and was referred to allauth + rest-auth.

I'm trying to convert my endpoints and running into problems with models.

Firstly, my user model with djoser dropped the username in favor of email, and I moved first & last name to a one-to-one profile table and added zipcode to the user model -- effectively my users are emails with passwords and zipcodes.

allauth threw an error that username didn't exist, after searching around I found a hacky 'solution' in adding an empty username filed back into my user model (and just ignoring it). When I changed my login endpoint from `/auth/token/login/` to `/rest-auth/login/` I got another error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name 'first_name' is not valid for model 'User'.` I'd really like to avoid adding all of the profile fields into my user model and making them nullable -- and I don't really want to write my own authentication backend.

Does anyone have experience with this type of model overriding?

Cheers,
-E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are planning on completely avoiding Django's user infrastructure, I would not bother trying to remove the default fields.

Whenever you're [customizing the django user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user) you'll want to extend [AbstractBaseUser](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L316) which includes `first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `email`, `date_joined`, `is_staff`, and `is_active`. You don't have to use them but they will be there. [You can specify which field will be used for the username](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD)

Once you're using `AbstractBaseUser` as the base for your user class, your problems here will go away and you can specify what you need from `allauth` from their [configuration docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html).

Also see the [`allauth` doc on custom user models](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html?highlight=custom%20user%20models#custom-user-models)